# I'm trying to display data from my database in table, but don't want to appear, I don't know what went wrong

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Here's my controller call "a_porto"

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->model('a_porto_models');
    $data = array();    
    $data['tampil'] = $this->a_porto_models->get_crud_all();    
    $this->load->view('a_porto_view', $data);
}
```

Here's my model call "a_porto_models"

```
function get_crud_all() {
    $query = $this->db->get('prototype');
    return $query->result();
}
```

And than my view call "a_porto_views"

```
<?php $tampil = array(); ?>
<?php foreach ($tampil as $a){ ?> 
<tr>
<td><?php echo $a->id_proto; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $a->foto; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $a->nama_pro; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $a->tahun; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $a->lokasi; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $a->deskripsi; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

What I've to do? My code doesn't show an error :(

Comment: Why have you tagged it [tag:java] seems like [tag:php]

Comment: oh I'm sorry I forgot

Answer (score 1):

Change to this code:

```
<?php foreach ($tampil as $a){ ?> 
<tr>
<td><?php echo $a->id_proto; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $a->foto; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $a->nama_pro; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $a->tahun; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $a->lokasi; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $a->deskripsi; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

You see null result because you reset your array to be empty. when its already have content from the controller sent to the view

Comment: if I changed the code like that, it will display an error message like "(Message: Undefined variable: tampil) (Filename: views/a_porto_view.php)" and "(Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()) (Filename: views/a_porto_view.php)"

Comment: @Kiki becuase in this line     $this->load->view('a_porto_view', $data);
you need to change to     $this->load->view('a_porto_views', $data);
becuase your filename is a_porto_views not view

Comment: @Kiki make sure you load proper view that actually exist and try to echo there some text. also remove $data = array();

Answer (score 0):

Remove $tampil = array(); and try again. You are basically setting your result to an empty array there.